# Help with colours

Tags: color, color-theory

I would say I've always struggled with colour combinations so I'm hoping someone can help.

How do you all choose your colour combinations?

I tend to look at https://coolors.co and generate a colour scheme but thats all I've got.

Most of the time I am given a 1 or 2 colours from the company and I need to create a theme around them.

I can get the basics looking ok but I really struggle when it comes to buttons and hover states / tones.

I've attached a design which I am really struggling with, I have the main colour but I don't like the dark grey colour when hovering but I can't find a colour that works without looking odd.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Dan, your question is **very** broad, but I think there's an *underlying* misunderstanding: you've tagged with colour-theory, but you don't actually have a colour-theory question; you have posed a wide-open, opinion-driving query based on the idea that it's all just a "feel" thing - that it's about what we "feel" looks nice together. There is, for certain, a subjective, judgement-based aspect to colour choices, *but* it's also driven by experience, training and study. If you look up "triad schemes" or "complimentary schemes" or "analagous schemes" and look at a colour wheel, this may help.